# Assertion intention: assert(!distNodePt == !indexNodePt)

Tags: c++, pointers, assertion

What is this assertion intention? For some reason, I cannot make sense out of it.

```cpp
// Instantiate pointers of two custom types
FloatNodeType      * distNodePt  =  distAcc.probe(origin);
Int32NodeType      * indexNodePt = indexAcc.probe(origin);

assert(!distNodePt == !indexNodePt); // What is this assertion trying to make sure?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `assert(!distNodePt == !indexNodePt); // What is this assertion trying to make sure?`

This checks that either *both* pointers are pointing to valid memory, or that *both* pointers are equal to `nullptr`.

Note that the `!` is necessary, otherwise you'd be comparing the actual addresses, which is not the same thing.